# Split a string into different arrays

Tags: c#

I'm trying to split a string into two different array. Basically, I would like to work like this: `StreamReader` reads a line like this:

> name|type|path

And separates "name", "type" and "path" by '|'. Then add them to their array ("name" go to array "name", "type" to "type" array and the "path" to the "path" array), but I can not think of any way to do that.

Preferably I would like these three arrays stay in a list of arrays.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+Split+a+string should get you started. Your really should not be using arrays of arrays as data structure - feel free to find good duplicate that explains proper approach with classes for each record.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I had sought about it. Unfortunately posted here the solution and I would accept the answer, but because of a negative vote, the guy went out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this hope it will solve your problem

```
var yourstring = "name|type|path";
string[] yourarrayname = yourstring.Split('|');
var name = yourarrayname[0];
var type=yourarrayname[1];
var path = yourarrayname[2];
```

Comment: How I can add the vars into a List<string[]>?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a stream reader, you may want to go like this:

```
List<char> chars = new List<char> ();

List<string> names = new List<string>();
List<string> types = new List<string>();
List<string> paths = new List<string>();

int index = 1;
while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
{
  char ch = (char)reader.Read();

  if (ch == '|')
  {
    switch(index)
    {
      case 1: names.Add( new String(chars.ToArray()));
      case 2: types.Add( new String(chars.ToArray()));
      case 3: paths.Add( new String(chars.ToArray()));
    }

    index = (index==3? 1: index+1);
    chars.Clear ();
    continue;
  }

  chars.Add(ch);
}
```